# Sending data among multiple Android devices

Tags: android, networking, wifi, p2p

I need a way to send data among multiple Android devices within around ~50 ft bidirectionally.
Basically the idea is that one device sends all the other devices within the area a small amount of data and all the other devices send back a small amount of data.

After a couple hours of research, I came across multiple ways to implement this: Wi-fi p2p, external server, etc.

As far as I know, Wi-fi P2P only let's you connect to one device at a time, which is not what I am trying to accomplish, since I need the device to communicate to multiple devices simultaneously. Also, this way limits my application to enforce the devices to be within the same wireless network.

Using an external server would allow as many devices to communicate with one another, but I have no idea how one device would detect devices within a vicinity using this method. I was thinking maybe the devices could communicate their coordinates to the server and have the server analyze the proximity of the devices connected, but I wasn't entirely sure.

I am pretty new to Android programming as well as network programming, so any help to guide me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Here's what I have so far. It has no networking elements to it yet. It simply accesses the stock music app and retrieves the current track information. I want to be able to send this information to all nearby devices.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";
public static final String CMDNAME = "command";
public static final String CMDTOGGLEPAUSE = "togglepause";
public static final String CMDSTOP = "stop";
public static final String CMDPAUSE = "pause";
public static final String CMDPREVIOUS = "previous";
public static final String CMDNEXT = "next";
public String song_artist = "";
public String song_track = "";
public String song_album = "";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);    
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.d("mIntentReceiver.onReceive ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        TextView music_info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.musicview);
        music_info.setText("Track: "+track+
                            "\nArtist: "+artist+
                            "\nAlbum: "+album);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Yeah I have a basic Android application that retrieves the data from the phone that I need to send (specifically, the information of the current music playing). If anyone has any example code that I can refer to start on this networking part, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you just post your code here? Or just parts of your code, if it's "secret"..

Comment: Done. I don't have any networking elements added to the code yet though.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done exactly this. It may well be overkill for you, but was required for us, so sharing regardless. I had written a TCP server, which reacted on commands. Unfortunately, this wasn't ideal as it wasn't conversational enough. I've since opted for XMPP. Using OpenFire XMPP server (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) (Think Google's Cloud Messaging service) - I've created a small client bot, which still acts on commands and sends back to each device requesting information. You can also do a mass broadcast to all attached clients too. It was shocking just how easy it was to set up.

You'll also need the API for your Java/Android application, which can be found here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

It does have the added overhead of a middle-man server, but all devices will be able to communicate with ease, plus if any devices go 'offline' (for whatever reason), the server will pool the messages and send once they've reconnected.

Hopefully this helps!

RE: the location of each device, you could send geolocation coords, and have a small algorithm work out the finer details. It would be a start at least.